# Is using NSArray in Codable possible? (transforming "Object Mapper" to "Codable")

Tags: ios, swift, codable, objectmapper, decodable

I am trying to transform "Object Mapper" to "Codable". My response which comes from service includes `NSArray` which includes custom objects. I need to use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Codable Class. But, i failed.I tried to use third party library like [AnyCodable](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable), but, i failed again. I can't change the response on server side. It must come as Array. I must use Array. Do you have any suggestion or information?

```
class Person : Codable { //Error 1
  var name: String?
  var data: NSArray?

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
      case name
      case data
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
      try container.encode(data, forKey: .data) //Error 2
  }

  func decode(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      self.data = try container.decode(NSArray.self, forKey: .data) //Error 3
  } 
}
```

> **Error 1:** "Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"
>
> **Error 2:** "Argument type 'NSArray' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'"
>
> **Error 3:** "Instance method 'decode(_:forKey:)' requires that 'NSArray' conform to 'Decodable'"

Sample response is here.All items in the array don't have the same contents. Every item in array has different type.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "languageCode": "EN",
      "deviceInformation": {
        "screenSize": "height:812.0 width:375.0",
        "connectionType": "wifi",
        "deviceType": "iPhone",
        "deviceCode": "D01D304C-D05C-4443-9A92-031C55D14XC7",
        "operatingSystemVersion": "12.2",
        "applicationVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "lastUpdatedParamDate": "13.05.2019 14:44:24",
      "skipOptionalUpdate": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use Array not NSArray. What is the content of data (the array)?

Comment: I tried it.When I use Array<Any>. I failed again. "Any" does not conform ...... same error. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes, you need give the exact type. You write "custom objects", of the same class or? You need to include the definition of that custom class as well.

Comment: The content of data is not constant. It can be everything. First index = Int, Second index = String, Third index = Object.

Answer (score 1):

When you make it

```
var data: NSArray?
```

it's a bridged objective - c type that have `Any` as the type of elements and Any doesn't conform to `Codable` so explicitly make it the type like

```
var data:[SomeModel]
```

or use `JSONSerialization` instead

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: [Model]
}

struct Model: Codable {
    let languageCode: String
    let deviceInformation: DeviceInformation
    let lastUpdatedParamDate: String
    let skipOptionalUpdate: Int
}

struct DeviceInformation: Codable {
    let screenSize, connectionType, deviceType, deviceCode: String
    let operatingSystemVersion, applicationVersion: String
}
```

---

```
let eventData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

> if you have more attributes you can add them , if some returns `nil` in some cases make them optional , but if the type changes then no way with Codable

Comment: The content of data is not constant. It can be everything. First index = Int, Second index = String, Third index = Object.

Comment: then `Codable` can't be used go with `JSONSerialization`

Comment: I shared sample response. Is it impossible with Codable?

Comment: Yes, i know this solution but i have a lot of response like that. I need general thing.

Comment: I have not only DeviceInformation and Model. I have a lot of Model like that in NSArray. I need to find general thing.

Comment: if you have more attributes you can add them if some returns nil in some cases make them optional , but if the type changes then no way with Codable

Comment: Yes, type is changing at every response and at every index. Okay, i understood. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you add this comment on your post? For others?? @Sh_Khan

Comment: I know this way. But, all items in the array don't have the same contents. I shared the response, check it. @vadian

Comment: @Okan, if `data` content can be of different type you may try to use `Codable` `enum`.

Comment: @user28434 `enum` fits for 2 values , but if it exceeds that it will be a messy code with many switches around

Comment: @Sh_Khan, wut? Each `enum` case is just for separation of different cases, and it should just contain a **single** associated value of some `Codable` type. Like `enum Datum: Codable { case int(Int); case string(String; case object(SomeObject) }`

Comment: i'm talking about checking the type in your posted comment you would do a switch

Comment: @Sh_Khan, if you don't know the actual type you would "do a switch" anyways, only later in code.